# Yii captcha weird behaviour of the message errors

Tags: php, yii, captcha

Hi I'm trying to do my best at Yii captcha implementation but I am stuck. There are weird stuff.

**1.** Even if i write it correctly the message errors shows up. I have to press the "**Get a new code**" and after that  it will work. See the image:
[image]

**2.** This message errors is generate by on key event for some reason I guess. I want to generate the message error only when I press a submit button, which do a ajax request.

This is my **model**:

```
public $verifyCode;
....
 public function rules() {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.

        if ($this->scenario == "insert") {
            return array(
                array('requisition_id, sync', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
                array('lastname, firstname, email, dob, phone, cv_path, experienceMonths, experienceYears, competencies, token', 'required', 'message' => "Câmpul este obligatoriu"),
                array('email', 'email', 'message' => "Emailul este invalid!"),
                array('dob', 'validateDob'),
                array('dayOfBirth, monthOfBirth, yearOfBirth', 'safe'),
                array('taleo_id, sync', 'required', 'on' => 'taleoUpdate'),
                array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'captchaAction'=>'site/captcha') 
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            );
        } else if ($this->scenario == 'taleoUpdate') {
            return array(
                array('taleo_id, sync', 'required'),
                // The following rule is used by search().
                // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            );
        }
        else if($this->scenario == 'notjobapply'){
            return array(
                array('lastname, firstname, email, phone, cv_path, requisition_id', 'required', 'message'=>'Câmpul este obligatoriu'),
                array('email', 'email', 'message' => "Emailul este invalid!"),
            );
        }
}
```

and this is the **controller**

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow', 
                'actions'=>array('aplica', 'captcha'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    } 
....
$this->render('apply', array(
            "applicant" => $model, 
            'job' => $job, 
            'region' => $region,
            'captcha'=>array(
                'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
                'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
            ),
        ));
```

and finally the **view**:

```
<?php 

        if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()){ ?>

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($applicant,'verifyCode'); ?><br>
        <?php  $this->widget('CCaptcha', array('captchaAction'=>'site/captcha')); ?> <br><br>
        <?php echo $form->textField($applicant,'verifyCode'); ?><br>

        <?php echo $form->error($applicant,'verifyCode'); ?><br><br>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the user model validation rules i use these:

```
public function rules()
{        
    return array(
        array('isActive, parentId, role, ban, isLegalEntity, organization, discount, paymentDelay, debtLimit, PaymentMethod, ShippingMethod, KnowingSource, scopeOfActivity, ShablonId, agree, Group', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true), 
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on' => 'register'),    
        ...
     ),
 },
```

What if you try the same: `array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements(),'on' => 'register')` ?

Also make sure in your controller you've defined the captcha action like these:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function actions()
   {
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
         'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFF2F2F,
         ),
      );
   }     
   ....
}
```

Comment: If I let with 'on' => 'register' it does not matter what i write cuz it pass, as a result is not working. I found smth afte a long search, This code: <?php echo $form->error($applicant,'verifyCode', array(), false, false); ?> I added in the view at it is working. don't ask me why. I don't know

Comment: actually , for the first time it does not work if i write it correctly, but after it , it refresh itself again and after that it is working